# R sjPlot error message: Error in sjt.lm(fit1, fit2) : could not find function "sjt.lm"

Tags: r, data-science, data-visualization, sjplot

I want the summary output of my linear regression models neatly presented.

The HTML tables in this tutorial https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/03/beautiful-tables-for-linear-model-summaries-rstats/ is exactly what I want.

The problem's that when I try to run the example code from the tutorial, I get an error message: `Error in sjt.lm(fit1, fit2) : could not find function "sjt.lm"`

Thanks for any help!

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)
data(efc)
efc <- set_var_labels(efc, get_var_labels(efc))
fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data=efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data=efc)
sjt.lm(fit1, fit2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package has been updated since 2005. The new plot functionality is `plot_model()`. See website for more info: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This function is replaced by `tab_model()`

More details can be found here:  https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2017/10/23/one-function-to-rule-them-all-visualization-of-regression-models-in-rstats-w-sjplot/